# Integral Inequality: if $f:[0,1] \to (0,\infty)$ is continuous and if $\int_0^1 f(x)^2dx =7$ how to prove that $\int_0^1 f(x)^5dx>6+\int_0^1 f(x)^3dx$

Tags: integration, inequality

The following problem was proposed by Dan Sitaru in Romanian Mathematical Magazine:

> $\text{Let }f:[0,1]\rightarrow(0,\infty), f\text{ continuous}. \text{If:} \int_0^1 f^2(x)dx=7 \text{ then prove that:}$
>   $$\int_0^1 f^5(x)dx>6+\int_0^1 f^3(x)dx$$

My attempt:
Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality repeatedly on left side by breaking $5$ on to different numbers ($5=2+3$). I also played with Holder inequality. I was thinking to break 7 as 6+1 to be able to use the given equation.

Comment: You shold not edit the post by deleting the image, because it origins from the Facebook fanpage of the journal.

Comment: That is fine.  Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Observe that $$\int_0^1 \left(f^2(x)-1\right)dx=6.$$ Rewrite the desired inequality in the form $$\int_0^1 \bigl(f^5(x)-f^3(x)-6\bigr)dx=\int_0^1 \bigl(f^5(x)-f^3(x)-f^2(x)+1\bigr)dx>0.$$ Consider the polynomial $$p(t)=t^5-t^3-t^2+1=(t-1)^2(t+1)(t^2+t+1).$$ Obviously, $p(t)\ge 0$ on $[-1,\infty)$. So, the function $f$, being positive, has the property that $$\varphi(x):=f^5(x)-f^3(x)-f^2(x)+1\ge 0$$ for any $x\in[0,1]$. Then $$\int_0^1\varphi(x)dx\ge 0$$ and the weak inequality $$\int_0^1 f^5(x)dx\ge 6+\int_0^1 f^3(x)dx$$ is trivial.

Now we shall prove that the inequality is strict.

If $\varphi\equiv 0$, then by the factorization of $p$ and $f>0$ we infer that $f\equiv 1$ and the hypothesis $\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx=7$ is not fulfilled. Then (because of continuity of $f$), $\varphi>0$ on some subinterval $[a,b]\subset[0,1]$. On this interval $$\int_a^b\varphi(x)dx>0.$$ The integral on $[0,a]\cup[b,1]$ is nonnegative, so the integral on the whole $[0,1]$ is positive and the proof is finished.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another method for Hölder lover people, which seems to give a much better constant. Let me denote by $t := \|f\|_{L^5}$. Then by Hölder's inequality
$$
7 = \int_0^1 f^2 \leq t^2.
$$
Since the function $P(t) = t^5-t^3 = t^3(t^2-1)$ is increasing for $t\geq 1$, then for $t\geq \sqrt 7 \geq 1$, $t^5-t^3\geq P(\sqrt 7) = 42\sqrt 7$, and so
$$
\int_0^1 f^3 \leq t^3 \leq t^5 - P(\sqrt 7),
$$
which gives
$$\boxed{
42\,\sqrt 7 + \int_0^1 f^3 \leq \int_0^1 f^5.}
$$

---

**Remarks:**

- $42\,\sqrt 7 > 111$ which is much larger than $6$ ...
- The constant is optimal, as can be seen by taking $f(x) = \sqrt 7$.
- The proof works if one replaces $7$ by any number larger than $1$, with the corresponding change in the constant. In particular, the initial inequality with the number $6$ works as soon as $\|f\|_{L^2}^2 \geq 2.51$.