# if $f:[0,1] \to (0, \infty)$ is continuous and if $\int_0 ^1 f(x)^2 dx =7 $ how to prove that $\int_0 ^1 f(x)^5 dx > 6+\int_0 ^1 f(x)^3 dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality, definite-integrals

I saw this problem online:-

> if $f:[0,1] \to (0, \infty)$ is continuous and if $\int_0 ^1 f(x)^2 dx =7 $ ,I want to prove that $\int_0 ^1 f(x)^5 dx > 6+\int_0 ^1 f(x)^3 dx$

I tried multiple things but none of then lead to solution

because the $6$ and the $7 $ in the problem seems to imply that if I proved that $\int_0 ^1 f(x)^5 dx - \int_0 ^1 f(x)^3 dx > \int_0 ^1 f(x)^3  dx \int_0 ^1 f(x)^2  -1dx $ and $ \int_0 ^1 f(x)^3$ >1 will  solve the problem but the formula $\int_0 ^1 f(x)^5 dx - \int_0 ^1 f(x)^3 dx > \int_0 ^1 f(x)^3  dx \int_0 ^1 f(x)^2  -1dx $ is actually wrong but I am sure that this is not a number coincidence .

I tried to turn the integral to Riemann sum and use inequalities like Cauchy inequality or GM,AM,HM inequalites    , but I quickly realised that they wouldn't be very useful in this problem.

Comment: Actually, you can indeed prove it using Hölder's inequality, I added a new answer in the old post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3467268/integral-inequality. And you can get a much better constant $111$ instead of $6$.